# Multiple window managing: removing windows from window list

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**Description**

In my Electron program I store all visible renderer windows in a singly-linked list in the main process.
When a new one is created, it is added to the list but I am not sure how to remove them from the list again when they are closed (figuring out which list element to remove respectively).

**Code in Main process**

```
global.windows = new LinkedList();

function createWindow(p_URL, p_width, p_height, p_x, p_y, p_minWidth, p_minHeight, p_parent, p_icon) {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win;
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: p_width, height: p_height, minWidth: p_minWidth, minHeight: p_minHeight, parent: p_parent, icon: p_icon, show: false});

  global.windows.insert(win);
  if(p_URL !== undefined)
    win.loadURL(p_URL)

  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show()
  });


    console.log("added: size = " + global.windows.getSize());

  win.on('closed', () => {
    console.log("removeStart: size = " + global.windows.getSize());
    // Dereference the window object

    let i;
    for(i = global.windows.getHeadNode(); i.getData() !== win; i = i.next);

    if(i >= global.windows.getSize())
      console.log("Error");
    else
      global.windows.removeAt(i);

    console.log("i: " + i);
    console.log("removeEnd: size = " + global.windows.getSize());
    win = null;
  });

  return win;
}
```

**Question**

I tried to do it like this by traversing the list until I get to the element I want to remove and then removing it. When I now execute the program and then close one of the windows I get the following error.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Object has been destroyed
    at Error (native)
```

which is caused by the line `if(i >= global.windows.getSize())` which is in the eventlistener on `closed`. The log commands before that line produce an output but the ones after it don't do anything. No element is removed from the list.
What am I doing wrong? And is there maybe a better way how to manage the windows?